# $scope.data is undefined but $scope.data exists in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have here my javascript code:

```
 define(['controllers/controllers', 'services/alerts'], function(module) {
  'use strict';
  return module.controller('alerts', [
    '$scope', '$http', 'alerts', function($scope, $http, alerts) {
    console.log('alerts controller initialized');
    $scope.settings = {};
    return $scope.submit = function() {
      $scope.busy = true;
      console.log('scope', $scope);
      return console.log('data', $scope.data);
    };
  }
]);
```

});

I tried to log the contents of `$scope.data` that I expect to contain the values of `ng-model` => `data.followers` but always show undefined but when I tried to log value contents of `$scope`, `$scope.data` exists. As shown in the image:

[image: the log]

I tried initializing `$scope.data` but it will always return an empty array after changing the value of `ng-model` => `data.followers`. This is the code (in haml) when I initialized `ng-model`:

```
 %input{:type => "checkbox", "ng-checked" => "settings.#{$key}", "ng-model" => "data.#{$key}", "ng-true-value" => "true", "ng-false-value" => "false", "ng-click" => "submit()"}
```

Any thoughts?

### UPDATE:

Already fix this. All I did was to initialize $scope.data and used data.#{$key} in the ng-checked. That got me stuck. Noob angular programmer here.

Comment: Looks a bit confusing that you have two `alerts`, a service and a controller, not sure if this would cause issues. The convention is `AlertsCtrl`.

Comment: @elclanrs So if it is a service its AlertsService?

Comment: It's possible that the contents of `$scope.data` in the browser are attributes Angular, jQuery or even the browser give it, and not what you gave it. I know `_proto_` is an intrinsic property of JavaScript objects, but I'm not sure about `followers`.

Comment: @trysis `followers` is the attribute inside data. I've assigned it in that way via `ng-model = data.followers`

Comment: That would have been useful info in your question. Could you please add it? Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code you are using to initialize `data.followers`. Right now all you say is it is part of `ng-model`, which doesn't really tell us much.

Comment: @trysis Updated the question with the initialization of ng-model

Comment: @Jhn: It's more a case of lowercase vs uppercase. Controllers throughout the docs use this convention.

Comment: Is `followers` the only child of `$scope.data` (besides `__proto__`, which is JavaScript anyway, not Angular)? Also, you show where you initialize `followers`, but then you say you change it before loading the page. How do you do this?

Comment: @trysis It changes its value via a checkbox on click. I've attached in my haml code.

Comment: Oh, sorry. As I said, I don't read HAML. Are there any more attributes, though?

Comment: @trysis That's just it.

Comment: @Jhn By "That's just it", you mean there are no more attributes? Sorry, but that phrase can mean many different things based on accent, situation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When lazy loading Angular components, you need to use `$scope.$apply()`. When components are lazy loading using Require, or some other method, the functions are registered onto teh $scope outside of the `$digest` loop of Angular.  using `$scope.$apply()` makes the `$digest` aware of your bindings, and brings them inside the app instance.

You will likely also need to use `module.register.controller` instead of `module.controller`

```
define(['controllers/controllers', 'services/alerts'], function(module) {
  'use strict';
  return module.register.controller('alerts', [
    '$scope', '$http', 'alerts', function($scope, $http, alerts) {
    console.log('alerts controller initialized');
    $scope.settings = {};
    return $scope.submit = function() {
      $scope.busy = true;
      console.log('scope', $scope);
      return console.log('data', $scope.data);
    };
    $scope.$apply();
  }
]);
```

Comment: its still undefined and an error showed when I added $scope.$apply, Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Comment: could you create a plunkr?